# Imagemagick support for Ruby on Rails Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

was trying to download Window Binary Release for **ImageMagick** installation in `Windows 7` `Rails 4.2.4` , `Ruby 2.1.5`.

however all the download links returned `not found`.

[ImageMagick windows binary release link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

Are there any alternative links to **download** the file so that a proper **installation** can be done?

Answer (score 0):

I've just followed the link you provided, and tried:

```
http://www.imagemagick.org/download/binaries/ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-Q16-x64-dll.exe
ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/binaries/ImageMagick-6.9.3-7-Q16-x64-dll.exe
```

and a couple of others, and they all started a download. It's either a temporary thing with that server, or if permanent, your setup. Machine/ISP/Country comes to mind.

https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php

Also provides some mirrors, I see the German one has windows binaries.

Comment: thanks, it is accessible now. guess just met their server maintenance time.